# PHP query time() form mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want that my PHP checks if the time in the mysql db is the same, and if not that it will be changed.

This is what I got:

```
<?php
$last_time_check=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `time` FROM `servervars`");
if((time()-$last_time_check) >=1)
{
   mysqli_query($con, 'UPDATE `servervars` SET `time`='.$time.' WHERE ID=1');
}
?>
```

$con is the connection to the DB.
Current value 'time' in servervars: 1412448339
Value 'ID' is 1

I do something wrong, but I just cannot find where it's going wrong.

**The Fix**

I've removed the variable $last_time_check and only checked if the time could get changed. If this happends then it will send another message to the client.

```
mysqli_query($con, 'UPDATE `servervars` SET `time` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP() WHERE ID = 1 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - `time` >= 1');
    if ($con->affected_rows)
    {
        // at least 1 second has elapsed, do stuff
    }
```

Comment: Is the second query even executed?

Comment: Well... The first problem is in the if statement. The second is the second query. I just don't know how to fix it :/

Comment: [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) returns a [mysql_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object, not the actual result. That's why your if statement isn't working as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has an equivalent to `time()`, its the function `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`. Differently though, it can take a `DATETIME` as parameter to convert it into [UNIX time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), but when used without parameters its the same as `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())`.

```
UPDATE servervars SET time = UNIX_TIMESTAMP() WHERE ID = 1
```

**Update**

Ok so about the other issues. You are doing it all wrong. `mysqli_query` does not return the value directly. To fetch the value of `time` from the database, you need 3 steps:

```
$result = $con->query('SELECT `time` FROM `servervars` WHERE ID = 1'); // fetch result set
$row    = $result->fetch_row(); // fetch a row from the result set, as an array
$last   = $row[0]; // get the first element from the row you just fetched
```

Notice `$con->query()` can fail if theres a problem with the connection, the database, the table, or the query syntax itself, and `$result->fetch_row()` can fail if there are no results for the query. You should validate them before proceeding to the next step.

Alternatively, you can do this:

```
$con->query('UPDATE `servervars` SET `time` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP() WHERE ID = 1 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - `time` >= 1');
if ($con->affected_rows)
{
    // at least 1 second has elapsed, do stuff
}
```

This way we shortened your solution to a single query, that updates the field if necessary and report back that it happened or not..

Comment: Ok, thank you. But the problem starts at the if statement. Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 5 it says.

Comment: Thats because `mysqli_query()` returns an instance of `mysqli_result`, not the value of field `time` directly. You still have to use `mysqli_fetch_row` to obtan the values of the selected row.

Comment: Would you maybe update your Answer to the correct version for me? Because I am really not the best person with his. I just need to see how it works.

Comment: @Remco he kind of did.

Comment: @Mike yes I see :) I've updated my question, is this true or not?